# java: fast way to get image height and width from a URL

Tags: java, jsoup

I am using JSOUP to extract some information from given URL. My target is to get all image URL that are having minimum width W and min height H.

The problem is many site just use `src` but no `height` and `width` attribute. SO the only solution that i found was to use `BufferedImage` to get the image height and width of image but I think its not good choice if you have huge number of image

Is there some other way to get image height and width without creating the image first.

Comment: ImageIcon ii = new ImageIcon("image.jpg");
        ii.getIconHeight();
        ii.getIconWidth();

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
String location = "http://www.sxc.hu/pic/l/f/fa/fangol/1301370_97011830.jpg";
InputStream stream = new URL(location).openStream();
Object obj = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(stream);
ImageReader reader = ImageIO.getImageReaders(obj).next();
reader.setInput(obj);
System.out.println(reader.getWidth(0));
stream.close();
```

This is high-productive in reading width and height in every jdk.

Comment: It throws Input not set exception

Comment: @MathematicsBeginner Do you mean InputNotSetException? I do not know this exception!

Comment: it throws java.lang.IllegalStateException: getInput() == null

Comment: @ievgen Yes, the url is not available anymore. Althou, the code example works with other urls.

Comment: @Grim no, the snippet is not correct, you need to specify reader.setInput() for this to work (verified). Also 'next' is undefined in this example

Comment: @ievgen I had no such issue. But I could reproduce it using a 64-bit JDK. Try again please.

Comment: Works fine now !

Answer (score 0):

(I am late to game, but anyway)If you have used JSOUP then you can measure it with JSOUP. So let say have fetched it with following way:

> This is your JSOUP fetcher (you decide how to create it):

```
Document document=Jsoup.connect(your_url).get();
Elements elements=document.select("img[src]");
int length=elements.size();
```

> And then just use this to get heights:

```
for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
 String height=elements.get(i).attr("height");
 System.out.println(height);
}
```

Comment: "The problem is many site just use src but no height and width attribute"